# Building emacs 24.1.50

Tags: emacs, build

I've just updated to Kubuntu 12.04. Everything works fine except for the latest custom-build emacs. It says now:

```
emacs: symbol lookup error: emacs: undefined symbol: gtk_window_set_has_resize_grip
```

So I've decided to re-build emacs. For that I've `git pull` the latest snapshot, and have done everything as I usually do, but now I get an error during compilation:

```
In file included from /home/boris/its/blds/emacs/lib-src/emacsclient.c:76:0:
../lib/getopt.h:196:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct option’
/usr/include/getopt.h:106:8: note: originally defined here
../lib/getopt.h:245:12: error: conflicting types for ‘getopt_long’
/usr/include/getopt.h:175:12: note: previous declaration of ‘getopt_long’ was here
../lib/getopt.h:249:12: error: conflicting types for ‘getopt_long_only’
/usr/include/getopt.h:179:12: note: previous declaration of ‘getopt_long_only’ was here
make[1]: *** [emacsclient] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/boris/its/blds/emacs/lib-src'
make: *** [lib-src] Error 2
```

Google search reveals almost nothing on these errors.

**Edit**:

The following solves it (thanks to [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180112/json)):

```
git pull
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/home/boris/its/soft/Emacs_24.1.50
make bootstrap
make install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use PPA: [emacs-snapshot](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cassou/emacs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

Answer (score 2):

I had these problems updating to Ubuntu 12.04, and got past it by going back to the instructions from INSTALL.BZR for first time checkout - it seems the configure file needs to be regenerated due to changes in libc in the new version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to build emacs after a git pull (my [script](https://github.com/xaccrocheur/kituu/blob/master/scripts/px-build-emacs.sh) to do it nightly)

```
make distclean && autoreconf -i -I m4 && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem than the op, and i just removed emacs from the system, and compiled from scratch.

and no, i didn't have to add a ppa, and every time i see an answer like that getting all the votes, it makes me wonder about stackexchange in general , it just misinforms and misleads others who may have the same problem.

and no, i said it once and i'll say it again, Just download the latest emacs from fsf.

let me add that getopt.h is part of libc6-dev (as json said). and libc6-dev is part of the required group like libjpeg libncurses libpng libtiff xlibs etc. remove it once and reinstall. the problem is with the configuration options path which need to be specified this time around in the prefix of emacs24 at the time of configuration. but neither autogen nor bootstrap are necessary, but just make and make install.

Comment: I think both answers -- how to complile from scratch and the ppa one -- are valuable. If You prefer to compile everything Your self, and want to compile it over and over with each update (or use outdated stuff) -- that's just Your opinion.

Comment: yes. and i'm wrong for not clarifying that the answer with the most votes is correct in the sense that is the simplest fix, but not the solution. and you are wrong for not seeing that the error is caused by a conflict. conflict which is solved by removing emacs and compiling from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
make maintainer-clean
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10108#8

I had the same issue as you but for the 24.5 tag. The problem was I didn't rerun autogen.sh to create a new configure script. I assumed that any untracked file would be listed by git status, though all the configuration output from autogen.sh is ignored in .gitignore.